Node.js 'forever' module stops working intermittently without error messages
I am using forever to run my node application on Linux server. The problem that I am facing is that if my database server went down then app stops running and I have to start the forever again. I want to run the application no matter if there is any error in the application.(Error handling is done in the code.). Could you please tell is there any alternate that I can use instead of forever to run the application on server.
SQL Code :
sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(function(pool) { pool.request().query(query).then(function(results) { }.catch(function(err) { }); }).catch(function(err) { });

Error I am getting is
ConnectionError: Login failed

Share you error handling code

I am using try catch block in code.

the way you are handling the db error matters

sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(function(pool) {
pool.request().query(query).then(function(results) {
}.catch(function(err) {
        });

}).catch(function(err) {
    });

If connection is down then I will get the error:
ConnectionError: Login failed

Don't add details in the comments. Edit your question to be answerable or else people will vote to close it.
